# Android studio media player crashing app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I don't really know why my Media Player causes the app the crash whenever I click my play button. The code is below (excuse the stupid variable names).

```
package com.example.daud.myapplication;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class player_try_2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer playerOfSong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_try_2);
    }


    public void playTheSong(){
            playerOfSong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test1);
            playerOfSong.start();

    }
}
```

The `playTheSong()` method is set to the onClick for my button. Instead of coding this in, I did it through the button properties in design view. The R.raw.test1 file holds an mp3 file.

Any help with this is super appreciated. Thanks.

LogCat is showing this as the error:

```
07-22 00:22:52.790 11650-11650/com.example.daud.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.daud.myapplication, PID: 11650
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method playTheSong(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Call `playerOfSong.prepare();` before `start`

Comment: Tried that. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass a `View` parameter

Do this

```
public void playTheSong(View v){
        playerOfSong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test1);
        playerOfSong.start();

}
```

Comment: I was/am and that fixed it. Thank you so much. My reputation on stackoverflow is not enough to be able to up vote, but thank you!